# Is there a way to use an http proxy for google-cloud-cpp?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-cpp

I am using [google-cloud-cpp](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp) (C++ API for Google Cloud Platform functions) to create/read/write to buckets. When I am working from within the organization's firewall, I have to use a proxy to be able to connect to google cloud.
I see that we can configure a proxy using the gcloud command line:
gcloud config set proxy/type http
gcloud config set proxy/address x.x.x.x
gcloud config set proxy/port

Can I do something similar when I use google-cloud-cpp?

Comment: If you're in linux, normally you can set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` env vars

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the source code of the google-cloud-cpp library as found on GitHub, we seem to see that it is based on libcurl.

See:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/storage/internal/curl_handle.cc

Following on from the comments by @Travis Webb, we then look at the docs for libcurl and find:

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html

This documents API that can be used to set proxy settings for programs that use libcurl.  However, if we read deeper, we find a section on environment variables that declares that `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` can be set.