# Configure google cloud lib to upload and download files via proxy

Tags: c++, google-cloud-storage

I use google cloud cpp library to upload and download files. 
 Does this library have some API to configure proxy using C++ code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this question and its answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530120/is-there-a-way-to-use-an-http-proxy-for-google-cloud-cpp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use an http proxy for google-cloud-cpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530120/is-there-a-way-to-use-an-http-proxy-for-google-cloud-cpp)